# How to plot and analyze a simple grain yield trial?

Tags: experiment-design, references, tukey-hsd-test

I am looking for a common trial design for comparing 6 different sunflower cultivars, and a way to analyze it as a part of a course I am taking.

The common know-how in my class is to set the trial in 4  randomized blocks, each plot with 50-100 plants, gather the grain as bulk from each plot, and compare the means in TUKEY on the jmp software by SAS.

Is that the right way to approach this yield comparison?
or is there a better way to perform the trial? (A book/article that can guide me step by step to design and analyze this kind of trial will be also helpful)
.....

Comment: Is that TUKEY not TUCKEY?

Comment: well...i think its goes without a c..

Comment: By "plot" do you mean make an illustration? Also, now I'm curious so please come back and answer to share your experience.